# Evaluate $\,\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, alternative-proof

How can I evaluate this limit.
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{x}$$
This is what I did:
$x\in \big(\frac{-1}{2},0\big)\;$ ; $\;\;\lfloor x\rfloor =-1 $
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)=\sin(-1)<0 \;\;\text{ and }\;\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} x =0^{-}$$
then
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\sin(\lfloor x\rfloor)}{x}=+\infty$$
What you think? Any other method ?

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: $\left]\frac{-1}{2};0\right[$
This notation is confusing.  Are that typos?  Did you mean $x \in (\frac{-1}{2}, 0)$

Comment: yes, the French use that notation.

Comment: @nickalh The notation $]a,b[$ for the open interval $\{x : a < x < b\}$ is relatively common in parts of Europe.  France, in particular.  There is no reason to demand that it be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to the left of $0$, $\sin(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ is about $-.84$.   So the left hand limit is $+\infty$.